# Ebean Many To Many RelationShip in Playframework

Tags: playframework, many-to-many, relationship, ebean

i would like to create a many to many relationship between two tables "Term" and "Synonym" but i dont now how to write them Models !! 
Any Help ! and thnx a lot.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please include a clear problem description and if possible some minimal code. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ok i will thnx !

Answer (score 0):

For that you will need 2 models. In `Term` class:

```
@Entity
public class Term extends Models {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Synonym> synonyms = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

In `Synonym` class:

```
@Entity
public class Synonym extends Models {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable
    private List<Term> terms = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And for your database structure it will look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE term {
    id CHAR(255)
}

CREATE TABLE synonym {
    id CHAR(255)
}

CREATE TABLE term_synonym {
    term_id CHAR(255),
    synonym_id CHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(term_id, synonym) // This is needed to avoid having the same many to many relation
}
```

`term_synonym` table is needed to maintain the relationship of @ManyToMany in database level.